# Sending parameters to remote website

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I want to create a very primitive mixpanel/kissmetrics/analytics clone.

Therefor I need to send data to a remote website for the purpose of logging it. It should send simple parameters like, foo=bar, foo2=bar2

How can I send data with javascript without being caught to cross domain policy?
Can you provide an example code?

Comment: Reminds me of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3506208/425809

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can send arbitrary HTTP requests to any domain you like; you just cannot read the response.

To send a GET request, create an `<img>` element and set its `src`.

To send a POST request, create a hidden `<form>` that submits to a hidden `<iframe>`, then submit it.